# Too much space after \times

Tags: spacing, times

The following code:

```
 f(\textcolor{red}{-3})= 4 {\times} ~ \underbrace{\textcolor{red}{(-3)}}_{parenth\`{e}ses !!}-1
```

results in too much space after \times:

[image]

How to get `(-3)` close to the multiplication?

Comment: you can hide the width of underbrace text but why ` {\times} ~ ` which removes the normal space around times and adds a word-space (which isn't normally used in mathematics)

Comment: I just think of the 'removes the normal space' and not the 'adds a word-space' ...

Comment: `{}` removes the normal space and `~` adds the space that you would normally get between words.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\mathclap` from `mathtools`:

[image]

A few more things:

- Consider using <s>`\mathrm`</s> `\text` for text in math mode. `\text` is context-aware, so if you are in an italic context, it will output italicized text. `\mathrm`, on the other hand, will discard any spaces, because it is still math-mode!
- As David Carlisle noted, don't use the space `~` after `\times`. There is no need for it there.
- Also, as @egreg and @Mico said in the comments, enclosing the `\times` in braces makes the spacing incorrect around it. You should, instead, enclose the whole `\underbrace{...}_{...}` in braces.

Code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
 \[f(\textcolor{red}{-3})= 4 \times {\underbrace{\textcolor{red}{(-3)}}_{\mathclap{\mathrm{parenth\grave{e}ses !!}}}}-1\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would tend tu use `\text` instead of `\mathrm` here.

Comment: I would too, until @DavidCarlisle showed [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43085464#43085464) earlier today :)

Comment: Don’t brace `\times`, but rather the whole `\underbrace`

Comment: Although I would use `\text` here, as this is a textual annotation (and could have needed multiple words) not an identifier like `max` that is just conventionally set in roman, for which I'd use `\mathrm`

Comment: In your current screenshot, TeX is treating the `-` ("minus") symbol in front of "1" as a unary operator. As @egreg has already pointed out, you should encase the entire `\underbrace{...}_{...}` construct in curly braces. That way, TeX will also treat the `-` symbol as a binary operator. And, do remove the curly braces around `\times`. Oh, and since `mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically, there's no need to load `amsmath` separately.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thank you all for the tips :)

Comment: Explanation: `\underbrace{...}_{...}` makes an Op atom (like `\sin`, for instance) and this causes incorrect spacing (in this and other cases) in front or behind it: bracing the whole part makes it into an Ord atom, which is what's needed here.

Answer (score 4):

You can also hide the width of `parentheses!!` by `\makebox[0pt]{parentheses!!}`. You only need to adjust the size to match a subscript using `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
f(\textcolor{red}{-3})= 4\times{\underbrace{\textcolor{red}{(-3)}}_{\makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize parenth\`eses!!}}}-1
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]